# setup.py how to specify that I depend on optional dependency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, setup.py

Specifically, I want to use `pywebview`, which must be installed with either `pywebview[gtk3]` or `pywebview[qt5]` and so on.

It doesn't make sense to use this project without any of these dependencies (you absolutely must have one that matches your platform), but for some reason they are optional, so aren't installed by default.

I cannot find the correct syntax to specify these dependencies in my `setup.py`.

---

This is something I tried:

```
install_requires=[
    ...
    'pywebview >= 2.0.3',
    'pywebview[qt5];platform_system=="Linux"',
    'pywebview[winforms];platform_system=="Windows"',
    'pywebview[cocoa];platform_system=="Darwin"',
    'vext >= 0.7.0',
    'vext.gi >= 0.7.0',
]
```

But I have no way of verifying whether this will work.  There's zero documentation on possible values of `platform_system`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use platform specific dependancies:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='spam',
    version='0.0.1',
    extras_require={
        ':sys_platform == "win32"': [
            'qt5'
        ],
        ':"linux" in sys_platform': [
            'gtk3'
        ]
    },
    install_requires=[
        'pywebview'
        ],
)
```

Comment: Are you sure? How will it know that extras are related to `pywebview` and not some other package? I thought `extras_require` was for my optional dependency, not for dependencies of my dependencies...